# if else can't get the right value to return

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am using  sliding scale get value and return input box.

and i am checking else if condition , 
function return value first time output right Ui.value = 10 , but 2 time display sliding scale value

How to check condition ?

```
$("#sliders #slider-range-min").slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 0,
      min: 0,
      max: 5500,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
         if (ui.value >= '1' && ui.value <= '1000' ) {
           ui.value = 10;
         }      
         else if (ui.value >= '10001' && ui.value <= '24999' ) {
            ui.value = 25;
           //console.log(ui.value);
         }
         else if (ui.value >= '25000' && ui.value <= '54999' ) {
            ui.value = 50;
         }
         else if (ui.value >= '55000') {
            ui.value = 100;
         }
         console.log(ui.value);
         return $("#sliders #amount3").val("$" + ui.value);
      }
});
```

Comment: Alright... now, how is this PHP?

Comment: Your first conditional matches values between 1 and 1,000, but the next conditional jumps to 10,001.

Comment: like @TomErikStøwer said, you second else if has a jump of 9000.

Comment: Also, you could be experiencing strange things since you're comparing numbers with strings, even though javascript "casts" them "properly". :)

Comment: why you are comparing values with string **'1'** ?

Comment: help with how to compare this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i got the solution...

use the following code

```
$("#sliders #slider-range-min").slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 0,
      min: 0,
      max: 5500,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.value >= '1' && ui.value <= '1000' ) {
        ui.value = 10;
      }      
      //else if (ui.value >= '10001' && ui.value <= '24999' ) {
      else if (ui.value >= '1001' && ui.value <= '2499' ) { // 
        ui.value = 25;
        //console.log(ui.value);
      }
      //else if (ui.value >= '25000' && ui.value <= '54999' ) {
      else if (ui.value >= '2500' && ui.value <= '5499' ) {
        ui.value = 50;
      }
      //else if (ui.value >= '55000') {
      else if (ui.value >= '5500') {
         ui.value = 100;
      }
      console.log(ui.value);
        return $("#sliders #amount3").val("$" + ui.value);
      }
    });
```

try the fiddle too [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qzr9grub/)

hope it helps.........